# So more elements on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 600 elements on page. When all element is loaded page doesen't have lags but after

Element

```
 $.each(dishs, function(v, k){

                $.each(k.dishs, function(v, dish){

                    if( check_criterion(dish.criterion_first, dish.criterion_second) && dish.price >= default_settings.min && dish.price <= default_settings.max && dish.name.toLowerCase().indexOf( default_settings.search ) + 1 )
                        show = ' style="display: block;" ';
                    else
                        show = ' style="display: none;" ';

                html += '<form crit_2="' + dish.criterion_second + '" crit_1="' + dish.criterion_first + '" name="'+ dish.name +'" price="'+ dish.price +'" '+ show +' action="/order/" method="post" class="add_to_cart_close block col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">';
                    html += '<input type="hidden" value="' + dish.id + '" />';

                    html += '<div class="item">';
                        html += '<div class="b-img" style="position: relative;">';

                            html += '<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; top: 0px; left: -5px;">';
                            if(dish.criterion_first){
                                html += '<div class="ic criterion_' + dish.criterion_first + '" style="">';
                                    html += '<img alt="" src="/static/img/ci' + dish.criterion_first + '.png"  width="20px" height="20px">';
                                    html += '<span>' + criterion_list["item" + dish.criterion_first ] + '</span>';
                                html += '</div>';
                            }
                            if(dish.criterion_second){

                                html += '<div class="ic criterion_' + dish.criterion_second + '" style="">';
                                    html += '<img alt="" src="/static/img/ci' + dish.criterion_second + '.png"  width="20px" height="20px">';
                                    html += '<span>' + criterion_list["item" + dish.criterion_second ] + '</span>';
                                html += '</div>';
                            }
                            html += '</div>';
                            html += '<div class="img">';

                            if(!dish.image) {

                                html += '<div style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 170px; background-image: url(/static/img/no_image.png); background-position: 50%; background-size: cover;" ></div>';

                            }  else {

                                html += '<div style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 170px; background-image: url(/media/' + dish.image + '); background-position: 50%; background-size: cover;" ></div>';
                            }

                            html += '</div>';
                            html += '<div class="slider-img">';
                                html += '<div class="slider">';

                                    if(!dish.image_all.length) {

                                        html += '<div class="slide">';
                                        html += '<img data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPopup_' + dish.id + '"  alt="" src="/static/img/no_image.png">';
                                        html += '</div>';

                                    }  else {

                                        $.each(dish.image_all, function(v, image ) {

                                            html += '<div class="slide">';
                                                html += '<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPopup_' + dish.id + '" href="#" onclick="return false;" style=" display: block; width: 100%; height: 276px; background-image: url(/media/'+ image +'); background-position: 50%; background-size: cover;" ></a>';
                                            html += '</div>';

                                        });

                                    }
                                html += '</div>';
                            html += '</div>';
                                        html += '</div>';
                                        html += '<div class="title"><a href="#">' + dish.name + '</a></div>';

                                        if(dish.weight) {

                                            html += '<div class="massa">' + dish.weight + '</div>';

                                        }

                                        html += '<div class="desc" style="height: 120px; overflow: hidden;">';
                                            html += dish.description;
                                        html += '</div>';
                                        html += '<div class="bottom">';
                                            html += '<div class="left">';
                                                html += '<div class="cost"><span class="fix_price">' +  dish.price + '</span> <span class="rub">a</span></div>';
                                            html += '</div>';
                                            html += '<div class="right">';
                                            if(dish.supplements.length) {
                                                html += '<input data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPopup_' + dish.id + '"  type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="ЗАКАЗАТЬ">';
                                            }  else {
                                                html += '<input dish_id="' + dish.id + '" shop_id="' + dish.shop_id + '"  type="submit" class="add_to_cart btn btn-default" value="ЗАКАЗАТЬ">';
                                            }
                                            html += '</div>';
                                        html += '</div>';
                                    html += '</div>';
                                html += '</form>';

                                html += '<div class="modal fade product-modal bs-example-modal-lg" id="modalPopup_'+ dish.id +'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">';
                                  html += '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">';
                                    html += '<div class="modal-content">';
                                      html += '<div class="modal-body">';
                                        html += '<div class="row">';
                                            html += '<!-- slider -->';
                                            html += '<div class="col-sm-4">';
                                                html += '<ul>';
                                                    $.each(dish.image_all, function(v, img){

                                                        html += '<li style="width: 270px;"><img src="/media/'+ img +'" /></li>';

                                                    });
                                                html += '</ul>';
                                                html += '<div class="slider">';
                                                html += '<div class="icons">';
                                                    html += '<span class="likes"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> 4,8</span>';
                                                    html += '<span class="expert-count"><img src="/static/img/expert.png" width="22px"> 3</span>';
                                                    html += '<span class="reviews-count"><img src="/static/img/speach.png" width="20px"> 5</span>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                                html += '<div class="reward">';
                                                    html += '<span class="rewi1"><img src="/static/img/ico/i1.png" width="20px"> Блюдо без мяса</span>';

                                                html += '</div>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                            html += '</div>';
                                            html += '<!-- / slider -->';

                                            html += '<div class="info-product col-sm-8">';
                                                html += '<div class="headline">' +dish.name + '</div>';
                                                html += '<div class="product-value">Вес '+ dish.weight + ' </div>';
                                                html += '<div class="product-description">';
                                                    html += '<p style=" overflow: hidden;padding: 5px; text-overflow: ellipsis;" >';
                                                        html += dish.description;
                                                    html += '</p>';
                                                html += '</div>';

                                                if(dish.criterion_first || dish.criterion_second) {

                                                    html += '<div class="product-composition"><b>Состав:</b>';
                                                        if(dish.criterion_first) {
                                                            html += criterion_list[dish.criterion_first];
                                                        }
                                                        if(dish.criterion_second)
                                                        {
                                                            html += criterion_list[dish.criterion_second];
                                                        }
                                                    html += '</div>';

                                                }

                                                html += '<div class="supplements">'

                                                    if(dish.supplements.length) {

                                                        html += '<div class="row">';
                                                        html += '<div class="title">Добавки:</div>';

                                                        $.each(dish.supplements, function(v, supp){

                                                            html += '<div class="row-check col-sm-6">';
                                                            html += '<input price="'+ supp.price + '" class="supplement_price" value="'+ supp.id +'" type="checkbox">';
                                                            html += '<label>';
                                                            html += '<span class="name">';
                                                            html += supp.name;
                                                            html += '</span>';
                                                            html += '<span class="text-right price-plus fix_price">';
                                                            html += supp.price;
                                                            html += '</span> р.';
                                                            html += '</label>';
                                                            html += '</div>';

                                                            });

                                                        html += '</div>';
                                                    }

                                                    html += '<div class="total-price">';
                                                        html += '<div class="col-sm-12 line"></div>';
                                                        html += '<div class="row">';
                                                            html += '<!--<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">Цена:</div>';
                                                            html += '<div class="col-sm-8 text-right" style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;">';
                                                                html += '<span class="fix_price">'+ dish.price +'</span><span> р.</span></div>-->';
                                                            html += '<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">Цена:</div>';
                                                            html += '<div class="col-sm-8 text-right">';
                                                                html += '<span class="fix_price supplement_total_price" price="' + dish.price + '" >';
                                                                    html += dish.price;
                                                                html += '</span>';
                                                                html += '<span style="margin-right: 50px"> р.</span>';
                                                                html += '<button shop_id="' + dish.shop_id + '" dish_id="' + dish.id + '" data-dismiss="modal" class="add_to_cart btn btn-btn-cart">Заказать</button>';
                                                            html += '</div>';

                                                            if($('#user').val()) {
                                                                var display = 'block';
                                                                if(dish.favsdish)   var display = 'none;';

                                                                var dis_fav = 'none';
                                                                if(dish.favsdish)   var display = 'block';

                                                                html += '<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">&nbsp;</div>';
                                                                html += '<div class="col-sm-8 text-right" dish_id="' + dish.id + '" style="margin: 10px 0;">';
                                                                html += '<button dish_id="' + dish.id + '" style="margin-left: auto; cursor: pointer; display:' + display + ' " class="add_to_favs btn btn-btn-cart" >В избранное</button>';
                                                                html += '<button dish_id="' + dish.id + '" style="margin-left: auto; cursor: pointer; display: '+ dis_fav  +'" class="remove_from_favs btn btn-btn-cart" >Убрать из избранного</button>';
                                                                html += '</div>';
                                                            }

                                                        html += '</div>';
                                                    html += '</div>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                            html += '</div>';
                                        html += '</div>';
                                html += '<!--';
                                        html += '<div class="row">';
                                            html += '<div class="complete-product">';
                                                html += '<div class="headline col-sm-12">Это блюдо входит в обед:</div>';
                                                html += '<div class="item col-md-3 col-xs-4 col-sm-3">';
                                                    html += '<div class="image"><img src="img/slide.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>';
                                                    html += '<div class="name">Суп "Кокетка"</div>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                                html += '<div class="item col-md-3 col-xs-4 col-sm-3">';
                                                    html += '<div class="image"><img src="img/slide.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>';
                                                    html += '<div class="name">Грибочки "А ля рус"</div>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                                html += '<div class="item last col-md-3 col-xs-4 col-sm-3">';
                                                    html += '<div class="image"><img src="img/slide.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>';
                                                    html += '<div class="name">Мохнатое мороженое</div>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                                html += '<div class="product-cart col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-3 text-right">';
                                                    html += '<span class="price">345 р.</span><button class="btn btn-cart">Заказать обед</button>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                            html += '</div>';
                                        html += '</div>';
                                      html += '-->';
                                        html += '<div class="expert">';
                                            html += '<div class="headline">Мнение эксперта</div>';
                                            html += '<div class="row">';
                                                html += '<div class="image col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">';
                                                    html += '<img src="/static/img/rev1.png" alt="">';
                                                    html += '<div class="icons">';
                                                        html += '<div class="likes text-center"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> 4,9</div>';
                                                    html += '</div>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                                html += '<div class="info col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xs-9">';
                                                    html += '<div class="name">Владислав Фенечкин, эксперт с 11 летним стажем</div>';
                                                    html += '<div class="text">Очень тонко и необычно подобраны имена в прототипе. Очень тонко и необычно подобраны имена в прототипе. Очень тонко и необычно подобраны имена в прототипе.</div>';
                                                    html += '<div class="show-more"><a href="#">Показать больше ответов экспертов</a></div>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                            html += '</div>';
                                        html += '</div>';
                                        html += '<div class="expert reviews">';
                                            html += '<div class="headline">Отзывы о блюде (7)</div>';

                                            html += '<!-- item -->';
                                            html += '<div class="row item">';
                                                html += '<div class="image col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">';
                                                    html += '<img src="/static/img/rev1.png" alt="">';
                                                    html += '<div class="icons">';
                                                        html += '<div class="likes text-center"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> 4,9</div>';
                                                    html += '</div>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                                html += '<div class="info col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xs-9">';
                                                    html += '<div class="name">Владислав Фенечкин, эксперт с 11 летним стажем</div>';
                                                    html += '<div class="text">Очень тонко и необычно подобраны имена в прототипе. Очень тонко и необычно подобраны имена в прототипе. Очень тонко и необычно подобраны имена в прототипе.</div>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                            html += '</div>';
                                            html += '<!-- / item -->';

                                            html += '<!-- item -->';
                                            html += '<div class="row item">';
                                                html += '<div class="image col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-3">';
                                                    html += '<img src="/static/img/rev1.png" alt="">';
                                                    html += '<div class="icons">';
                                                        html += '<div class="likes text-center"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> 4,9</div>';
                                                    html += '</div>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                                html += '<div class="info col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-xs-9">';
                                                    html += '<div class="name">Владислав Фенечкин, эксперт с 11 летним стажем</div>';
                                                    html += '<div class="text">Очень тонко и необычно подобраны имена в прототипе. Очень тонко и необычно подобраны имена в прототипе. Очень тонко и необычно подобраны имена в прототипе.</div>';
                                                html += '</div>';
                                            html += '</div>';
                                            html += '<!-- / item -->';

                                        html += '</div>';
                                      html += '</div>';
                                    html += '</div>';
                                  html += '</div>';
                                html += '</div>';

                });

                $('#menu_' + k.sm).next().html(html);
                html = '';
                check_visible_catalogs();
            });
```

I generate in from AJAX data: than i insert it on page
Got function Show and hide elements So: i try show and hide 600 elements

```
$('[id^="menu_"]').hide();
$('[id^="menu_"]').next().hide();
```

And Than:

```
$('[id^="menu_"]').show();
$('[id^="menu_"]').next().show();
$('[id^="menu_"]').next().children().show();
```

I Got so strong lags....

How i can fix that lags?

Comment: sure 5 plase w8 i will update question

Comment: You're probably running into an issue with the browser repainting all the different elements due to your manipulation of them. You'll need to use your browser's debug tools and look at the profiling tool especially to help narrow down your issue. There's no simple way to fix performance problems. Having less on the page would help though. Server side rendering would also be beneficial. I'm not sure about your case though since it's ambiguous.

Comment: Have you considered using a templating engine like this: http://handlebarsjs.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

`cildren()` return not first level elements In 600 element i have `3200 childrens